# error: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public" in template Function

Tags: c++

i have a class to move , colorize , set text ...etc any GUI In the Window:

```
class BasicOption
{
public : 
template <class T>
void SetPosition ( float x , float y , T const*Obj);
};
```

and define the function like this :

```
template <class T>
void BasicOption::SetPosition ( float x , float y , T const*Obj)
{
this->Obj->SetPosition(x ,y );
}
```

i have class to create a Window like this

```
class GUI_Window : public BasicOption

{
public:   // <-- This colon was added in response to some answers
GUI_Window(float const&width , float const&height String const&name)
};
```

OK every thing work correctly but if i call the SetPosition in the Main Function i get

```
error: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public"
```

main.cpp

```
GUI_Window *W ; // MyWindow
int WINAPI wWinMain ( HINSTANCE hInst , HINSTANCE hPrev , LPWSTR lmcmdline , int nShowCmd )
{
..............
...........
..........
...........

W->SetPosition ( 520 , 250 , W );


}
```

also i change the code like this

```
{
W->SetPosition <GUI_Window>( 520 , 250 , W );
}
```

but still have the same problem

/******/

Guys i found the problem

it is the linkage , i define the function in the main.cpp and it is work correctly 
but if i define it outside the main.cpp file i get error sow any help to link this function 
and define it outside main.cpp

Comment: i change the code but i have the same probleme

Comment: You should mark the place where you changed the code in the question, otherwise the next guy coming here will be very irritated!

Comment: Templates should be defined inline, not in a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

It's `public:` not `public` - and you're missing a semicolon.

```
class GUI_Window : public BasicOption

{
public:
    GUI_Window(float const&width , float const&height String const&name);
};
```

Comment: class BasicOption
{
public : 
template <class T>
void SetPosition ( float x , float y , T const*Obj);
};

Comment: @user722528: Show us complete code that reproduces the problem, and complete error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen that error message before, but you are missing a colon in

```
public
    GUI_window(...
```